# Приложение андроид останавливается при вызове AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Я новичок в андроид, работаю над проектом в котором требуется получить из сервера JSON объекты и вывести в layout, в предыдущем активити я авторизируюсь и получаю токен для авторизации, передаю его с помощью Intent

вот мой код:

```
package com.example.sanzharaubakir.fin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.IOException;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpEntity;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.methods.HttpGet;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.util.EntityUtils;

/**
 * Created by sanzharaubakir on 28.07.16.
 */
public class show extends Activity {
    LinearLayout l;
    As a;
    String[] s;
    String token;
    int n = 0;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_res);
        LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        setContentView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);
        s = new String[1000];
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        token = intent.getStringExtra("token");
        a.execute();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
        {
            TextView v = new TextView(this);
            v.setText(s[i]);
            linLayout.addView(v, linLayoutParam);
            final int finalI = i;
        }
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("Сканировать");
        linLayout.addView(b, linLayoutParam);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BarcodeScanner.class);
                intent.putExtra("token",token);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public class As extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            func();
            return null;
        }
    }
    public void func()
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://144.76.29.144:8001/warehouse/api/list/?access-token=<" + token + ">/");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            String line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(line);
            n = arr.length();
            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
                //s[i] = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("items");
                s[i] = arr.getJSONObject(i).toString();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

и XML файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground">

</LinearLayout>
```

при вызове метода `a.execute();` приложение крашится
вот что выдает Log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.sanzharaubakir.fin, PID: 17677
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sanzharaubakir.fin/com.example.sanzharaubakir.fin.show}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                    at com.example.sanzharaubakir.fin.show.onCreate(show.java:35)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: a у вас null. `a = new As();` забыли

Comment: к тому же в методе doInBackground результат возвращается `return null` 
то есть вся ваша работа в отдельном потоке никуда не возвращается, что бы там не делалось - всегда будет null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем коде несколько причин, по которым возвращается null.

Во первых: *a у вас null. a = new As(); забыли – Yura Ivanov*

Во вторых, если void - значит из метода `doInBackground()` возвращать ничего не нужно, делать `return null` нужно либо очень осторожно, либо вообще не делать.

Так же, советую наследоваться от `AppCompatActivity` - это тот же самый `Activity`, только с поддержкой старых версий.